# Why first enumeration of encrypting data takes so long

Tags: java, performance, encryption

I want to create performance test where I am encrypting data using AES with PKCPadding5/7 depends on provider(IBM or BouncyCastle) on aix system. My question is why first enumeration is so slow and other so fast ?

When I run test with parameters:

```
Padding: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
Provider: BC version 1.47
Number of iteration: 1000
```

results is:

```
Time: 392080057 ns
Time: 174662 ns
Time: 160906 ns
Time: 169938 ns
Time: 154344 ns
Time: 155125 ns
Time: 157344 ns
Time: 157203 ns
Time: 157611 ns
Time: 158123 ns
```

Parameters

```
Padding: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
Provider: IBMJCE version 1.7
Number of iteration: 1000
```

results is:

```
Time: 13410344 ns
Time: 185007 ns
Time: 182562 ns
Time: 170687 ns
Time: 203156 ns
Time: 189980 ns
Time: 182608 ns
Time: 174670 ns
Time: 176842 ns
Time: 174463 ns
```

Code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < pocetIteraci; j++) {
    String text = randomString(46);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    sifruj(padding, provider, generateVectot(),text);

    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    System.out.println("Time: " + time + " ms");
}

public static byte[] sifruj(String padding, Provider provider, IvParameterSpec finalniInicializacniVektor,String text)
        throws Exception {
    return zpracuj(padding, provider, text.getBytes("UTF-8"), finalniInicializacniVektor, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
}

public static byte[] zpracuj(String padding, Provider provider, byte[] data,
        IvParameterSpec finalniInicializacniVektor, int mode) throws Exception {
    final SecretKeySpec klicSpec = new SecretKeySpec(klic, ALGORITHM_AES);
    final Cipher sifra = Cipher.getInstance(padding, provider);
    sifra.init(mode, klicSpec, finalniInicializacniVektor);

    return sifra.doFinal(data);

}
```

**UPDATED:**

The most different (As I expected) is when creating first instance of cipher:

```
long timeTemp = System.nanoTime();
final Cipher sifra = Cipher.getInstance(padding, provider);
timeTemp = System.nanoTime() - timeTemp;
System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX " + timeTemp + " ns");
```

Why?

Comment: What is `randomString`? Does it use `SecureRandom` by any chance?

Comment: simple function which generate random string with certain length and yes is use SecureRandom which instance is crateted just once

Comment: Note that `SecureRandom` is usually a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) which needs some entropy to get started, which comes from something like [/dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random). This can take some time and so does all the classloading (it's about 50ms per class and there are tons of classes there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised answer**

There's time taken to load and JIT-compile the code on the first call - that's why typically benchmarks *don't* include the first run. (In fact, many JVMs re-JIT more and more aggressively, so the performance improves over time - so good benchmarks run code lots of times before timing it.)

Additionally, it's not unreasonable to think that a crypto provider may well do some one-time setup, especially if it's trying its best to get some decent entropy. (It could be using `SecureRandom` internally, for example.) You might want to time the `Cipher.getInstance`, `Cipher.init` and `Cypher.doFinal` method calls separately, to determine which is the slow part.

Finally, you haven't shown us all the code (`generateVectot`?) so there could be things lurking there.

**Initial answer**

Apparently `randomString` is:

> simple function which generate random string with certain length and yes is use SecureRandom which instance is crateted just once

Given that you're looking for something which is expensive (as creating and using a `SecureRandom` instance is) and only happens once, this sounds like a smoking gun to me.

I suggest you add timing (using [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), not `System.currentTimeMillis`) within `randomString` to test that hypothesis.

---

I'd also strongly suggest that you *don't* use the overload of `String.getBytes` which uses the platform default encoding - instead, always specify the encoding explicitly.

Comment: I extract randomString from counted time but result are still same. See updated code

Comment: @hudi: You haven't updated the results *at all* - I would be astonished if you got the *exact* same results, even running the same code, let alone running different code.

Comment: yes I updated code and result are really same. Your answer with randomString doesnt explain why first iteration is so long and other so fast even generating random string is still same

Comment: @hudi: I've updated my answer to include class loading and JIT. I'm still very suspicious of the numbers though... normally I'd expect benchmarks to vary *somewhat* over time. Although as you're using `currentTimeMillis`, you're not using a very accurate timer anyway...

Comment: @hudi: Okay, answer updated again. Basically this doesn't massively surprise me, but you could perform more diagnostics to work out what the slow part is.

Comment: so as I expected(And this question is about this) the most slow part of code in first iteration is final Cipher sifra = Cipher.getInstance(padding, provider);

Comment: @hudi: Right - so it takes a while to initialize the cypher for the first time, quite possibly because it's generating some entropy, or possibly requiring lots of classes to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Crypto providers usually takes a bit to load. This can be seen by forcing it to load. Here i try with the IBM JCE provider):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time to load: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Time to load: 72
```

My guess is that you hit this load time the first time you use anything from the provider.

Comment: I run this example on aix maschine with IBM jave where IBMJCE provider is already in security. This ust solve why BC takes so long because this provider isnt default added to java providers